# Using discrete custom color in a plotly heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, plotly

I'm trying to generate a `plotly` `heatmap`, where I'd like the colors to be specified by a discrete scale.

Here's what I mean:

Generate data with 2 clusters and hierarchically cluster them:

```
require(permute)
set.seed(1)
mat <- rbind(cbind(matrix(rnorm(2500,2,1),nrow=25,ncol=500),matrix(rnorm(2500,-2,1),nrow=25,ncol=500)),
             cbind(matrix(rnorm(2500,-2,1),nrow=25,ncol=500),matrix(rnorm(2500,2,1),nrow=25,ncol=500)))
rownames(mat) <- paste("g",1:50,sep=".")
colnames(mat) <- paste("s",1:1000,sep=".")
hc.col <- hclust(dist(t(mat)))
dd.col <- as.dendrogram(hc.col)
col.order <- order.dendrogram(dd.col)
hc.row <- hclust(dist(mat))
dd.row <- as.dendrogram(hc.row)
row.order <- order.dendrogram(dd.row)
mat <- mat[row.order,col.order]
```

Brake the values in `mat` to intervals and set a color for each interval:

```
require(RColorBrewer)
mat.intervals <- cut(mat,breaks=6)
interval.mat <- matrix(mat.intervals,nrow=50,ncol=1000,dimnames=list(rownames(mat),colnames(mat)))
interval.cols <- brewer.pal(6,"Set2")
names(interval.cols) <- levels(mat.intervals)
```

Using `ggplot2` I draw this `heatmap` this way (also having the `legend` specify the discrete colors and respective ranges):

```
require(reshape2)
interval.df <- reshape2::melt(interval.mat,varnames=c("gene","sample"),value.name="expr")
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(interval.df,aes(x=sample,y=gene,fill=expr))+
  geom_tile(color=NA)+theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.text.x=element_text(angle=90,vjust=1,hjust=0.5,size=6),panel.spacing=unit(0.025,"cm"),legend.key=element_blank(),plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"),legend.key.size=unit(0.25,"cm"),panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_line(size=0.25))+
  scale_color_manual(drop=FALSE,values=interval.cols,labels=names(interval.cols),name="expr")+
  scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE,values=interval.cols,labels=names(interval.cols),name="expr")
```

which gives:
[image]

This is my attempt to generate it with `plotly`:

```
plot_ly(z=mat,x=colnames(mat),y=rownames(mat),type="heatmap",colors=interval.cols)
```

which gives:

[image]

The figures are not identical. In the `ggplot2` figure the clusters are much more pronounced in contrast to the `plotly` figure.

Is there any way to parametrize the `plotly` command to give something more similar to the `ggplot2` figure?

Also, is it possible to make the `plotly` legend discrete - similar to that in the `ggplot2` figure?

Now suppose I want to `facet` the clusters. In the `ggplot2` case I'd do:

```
require(dplyr)
facet.df <- data.frame(sample=c(paste("s",1:500,sep="."),paste("s",501:1000,sep=".")),facet=c(rep("f1",500),rep("f2",500)),stringsAsFactors=F)
interval.df <- left_join(interval.df,facet.df,by=c("sample"="sample"))
interval.df$facet <- factor(interval.df$facet,levels=c("f1","f2"))
```

And then plot:

```
ggplot(interval.df,aes(x=sample,y=gene,fill=expr))+facet_grid(~facet,scales="free",space="free",switch="both")+
  geom_tile(color=NA)+labs(x="facet",y="gene")+theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.text.x=element_text(angle=90,vjust=1,hjust=0.5,size=6),panel.spacing=unit(0.05,"cm"),plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"),legend.key.size=unit(0.25,"cm"),panel.border=element_blank(),strip.background=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_line(size=0.25))+
  scale_color_manual(drop=FALSE,values=interval.cols,labels=names(interval.cols),name="expr")+
  scale_fill_manual(drop=FALSE,values=interval.cols,labels=names(interval.cols),name="expr")
```

Which gives:
[image]

So the clusters are separated by the `panel.spacing` and look even more pronounced. Is there any way to achieve this faceting with `plotly`?

Comment: What about using `ggplotly`?

Comment: For these dimensions converting the ggplot to plotly with ggplotly takes unreasonably long (many many minutes) - not really practical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking initially the same thing, which is to down-sample the gradient, but instead forcing harsher transitions seems to do the trick at least to make the colors more pronounced.

```
interval.cols2 <- rep(interval.cols, each=1000)
plot_ly(z=mat,x=colnames(mat),y=rownames(mat),type="heatmap",colors=interval.cols2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @R.S.. Any idea how to facet?

Comment: Hmmnnn, I'm not too familiar with plot_ly heatmap, but in heatmap.2 for instance you can add dummy NA column or row vector, and set the color assignment for NA values to white to introduce a separator. Assuming there is a similar option in plot_ly, if this is a result of a cluster then you would need to find out where the cuts are, or if the column order is known before hand, just add a NA vector (or matrix) between the 2 groups. You will need to introduce `""` colnames as well.

Answer (score 5):

Let's get a discrete colorscale

```
df_colors = data.frame(range=c(0:11), colors=c(0:11))
color_s <- setNames(data.frame(df_colors$range, df_colors$colors), NULL)
for (i in 1:12) {
  color_s[[2]][[i]] <- interval.cols[[(i + 1) / 2]]
  color_s[[1]][[i]] <-  i / 12 - (i %% 2) / 12
}
```

And get a nice colorbar by setting `ticktext` and squeezing it (`len=0.2`)

```
colorbar=list(tickmode='array', tickvals=c(1:6), ticktext=levels(mat.intervals), len=0.2)
```

---

[image]
All the code which needs to be added to your example

```
df_colors = data.frame(range=c(0:11), colors=c(0:11))
color_s <- setNames(data.frame(df_colors$range, df_colors$colors), NULL)

for (i in 1:12) {
  color_s[[2]][[i]] <- interval.cols[[(i + 1) / 2]]
  color_s[[1]][[i]] <-  i / 12 - (i %% 2) / 12
}


plot_ly(z=c(interval.df$expr), x=interval.df$sample, y=interval.df$gene, colorscale = color_s, type = "heatmap", hoverinfo = "x+y+z", colorbar=list(tickmode='array', tickvals=c(1:6), ticktext=levels(mat.intervals), len=0.2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answers of @Maximilian Peters and @R.S.:

Data:

```
require(permute)
set.seed(1)
mat <- rbind(cbind(matrix(rnorm(2500,2,1),nrow=25,ncol=500),matrix(rnorm(2500,-2,1),nrow=25,ncol=500)),
             cbind(matrix(rnorm(2500,-2,1),nrow=25,ncol=500),matrix(rnorm(2500,2,1),nrow=25,ncol=500)))
rownames(mat) <- paste("g",1:50,sep=".")
colnames(mat) <- paste("s",1:1000,sep=".")
hc.col <- hclust(dist(t(mat)))
dd.col <- as.dendrogram(hc.col)
col.order <- order.dendrogram(dd.col)
hc.row <- hclust(dist(mat))
dd.row <- as.dendrogram(hc.row)
row.order <- order.dendrogram(dd.row)
mat <- mat[row.order,col.order]
```

Colors:

```
require(RColorBrewer)
mat.intervals <- cut(mat,breaks=6)
interval.mat <- matrix(mat.intervals,nrow=50,ncol=1000,dimnames=list(rownames(mat),colnames(mat)))
require(reshape2)
interval.df <- reshape2::melt(interval.mat,varnames=c("gene","sample"),value.name="expr")
interval.cols <- brewer.pal(6,"Set2")
names(interval.cols) <- levels(mat.intervals)
interval.cols2 <- rep(interval.cols, each=ncol(mat))
color.df <- data.frame(range=c(0:(2*length(interval.cols)-1)),colors=c(0:(2*length(interval.cols)-1)))
color.df <- setNames(data.frame(color.df$range,color.df$colors),NULL)
for (i in 1:(2*length(interval.cols))) {
  color.df[[2]][[i]] <- interval.cols[[(i + 1) / 2]]
  color.df[[1]][[i]] <-  i/(2*length(interval.cols))-(i %% 2)/(2*length(interval.cols))
}
```

Plotting:

```
plot_ly(z=c(interval.df$expr),x=interval.df$sample,y=interval.df$gene,colors=interval.cols2,type="heatmap",colorscale=color.df,
        colorbar=list(tickmode='array',tickvals=c(1:6),ticktext=names(interval.cols),len=0.2,outlinecolor="white",bordercolor="white",borderwidth=5,bgcolor="white"))
```

[image]

It would be great if anyone can add:

1. How to facet or create a narrow border between the facets.
2. How to get the `colorbar` tick labels to appear exactly in the middle of each box in the `colorbar`

Comment: Regarding (2) now that @MaximilianPeters showed us how to hack the colorbar, can you check from tickmode down to the other parameters, reading it seems to hint there is a way to do this by setting tickmode to 'linear' and using 0tick and dtick, though I haven't tried it. https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter-marker-colorbar-tickmode

Comment: I played around with it a bit and failed. Hence my post was targeting someone experienced. If I manage to get it right I'll update my answr

Answer (score 1):

A nice way for creating discrete color breaks is given in [question 59516054](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516054/how-to-create-a-chloropleth-map-in-r-plotly-based-on-a-categorical-variable)
.
Given the offered `Z_Breaks` function, you can center the `colorbar` tick labels in the middle of each box by using the function:

```
tickpos <- function(nFactor) {
    pos <- unique((head(Z_Breaks(nFactor), -1)) + head(Z_Breaks(nFactor))[2] / 2) * (nFactor - 1)
}
```

and then assigning it to the `tickval` argument of `colorbar`:

```
colorbar <- list(tickvals = tickpos(nFactor), ticktext = names(colours))
```