# Discrete colorbar in R plotly

Tags: r, scale, plotly, heatmap

I am trying to produce a Heatmap with R plotly. This is the reproducible example:

```
test <- structure(list(s1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), s2 = c(1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), s3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), s4 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), s5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), s6 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6"
), row.names = c("5HT2 type receptor mediated signaling pathway", 
"5HT3 type receptor mediated signaling pathway", "5-Hydroxytryptamine degredation", 
"Alpha adrenergic receptor signaling pathway", "Alzheimer disease-amyloid secretase pathway", 
"Angiogenesis"), class = "data.frame")
```

And the code to produce the heatmap in plotly:

```
f1 <- list(
    family = "Arial, sans-serif",
    size = 5,
    color = "lightgrey")

f2 <- list(
    family = "Old Standard TT, serif",
    size = 10,
    color = "black")

a <- list(
  title = "",
  titlefont = f1,
  showticklabels = TRUE,
  tickangle = 45,
  tickfont = f2,
  exponentformat = "E")

plot_ly(z = as.matrix(test), 
        zmin=0, 
        zmax=1,
        x = colnames(test), 
        xgap = 2, 
        y = rownames(test), 
        ygap =2, 
        type = "heatmap", 
        colorbar=list(ypad = 30, tickmode="array", tickvals = c(0,1), color = 2, autocolorscale = F )) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = a,
         margin = list(l =500, r = 10, b = 200, t = 10))
```

[image]

As you see, the produced plot has a scale that is continuous. I have found this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42524450/using-discrete-custom-color-in-a-plotly-heatmap) where the author asked a similar question. I tried to replicate the solutions provided by the answers but I couldn't get to the bottom of it. Could you please tell me how to set the scale to discrete instead of continuous color ?

Thanks

EDIT1: Added "a" variable definition

Comment: Please, define `a` in `layout(xaxis = a, ...`

Comment: @MarcoSandri added in the main question, thanks for pointing it out !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define a color scale as follows:

```
colorScale <- data.frame(z=c(0,0.5,0.5,1),col=c("#440053","#440053","#FDE624","#FDE624"))
colorScale$col <- as.character(colorScale$col)

plot_ly(z = as.matrix(test), 
        x = colnames(test), 
        xgap = 2, 
        y = rownames(test), 
        ygap =2, 
        type = "heatmap", 
        colorscale=colorScale ,
        colorbar=list(ypad = 30, tickvals=c(0.25,0.75), ticktext=c(0,1))) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = a,
         margin = list(l =500, r = 10, b = 200, t = 10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer !

Could you please elaborate on your answer so I can understand what you did ? 

Thanks !

Comment: @Law A color scale is a data frame with a numeric column and a character column. The numeric column defines the ranges of values and the character column defines the colors for the corresponding ranges. I defined two ranges: from 0 to 0.5 with purple color and from 0.5 to 1 with yellow color. The defined color scale should then be passed to `plot_ly` using the `colorscale` argument.

Answer (score 4):

Macro Sandris answer is perfect and works like a charm.

I just want to add, that if you need more than two classes, you may do so by using the following example:

**2 classes (see Marcos answer)**

```
colorScale <- data.frame(z=c(0,0.5,0.5,1),col=c("#440053","#440053","#FDE624","#FDE624"))
```

**3 classes**

```
colorScale <- data.frame(z=c(0,0.33,0.33,0.66,0.66,1),col=c("#440053","#440053","#FDE624","#FDE624","#DDE431","#DDE431"))
```

and so on. Make sure the vector passed into the data frame always ranges from 0 to 1.