# Discrete colours in chloropleth map on plotly don't show all levels

Tags: r, maps, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to plot a map of Colombia's provinces and a factor variable with 8 levels, I'm using Long-Lat coordinates.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
> head(df[,c('CODMPIO','Esc2a','Longitud','Latitud')])
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  CODMPIO Esc2a Longitud Latitud
  <chr>   <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 05001   4        -75.6    6.25
2 05002   5        -75.4    5.79
3 05004   7        -76.1    6.63
4 05021   5        -75.1    6.38
5 05030   7        -75.7    6.04
6 05031   7        -75.1    6.91
```

and the geojson has the coordinates and these columns:

```
$properties
$properties$DPTOMPIO
[1] "05001"

$properties$DPTO_CCDGO
[1] "05"

$properties$MPIO_CCDGO
[1] "001"

$properties$MPIO_CNMBR
[1] "MEDELLÍN"

$properties$MPIO_CCNCT
[1] "05001"
```

> properties$DPTOMPIO

is the same as

> df$CODMPIO

Finally, all my code is this

```
df$Esc2a = factor(df$Esc2a)
df$test = as.numeric(df$Esc2a)
nfactor = length(levels(df$Esc2a))
foo <- brewer.pal(n = nfactor,name = "Set1")
names(foo) = levels(df$Esc2a)

Z_Breaks = function(n){
  CUTS = seq(0,1,length.out=n+1)
  rep(CUTS,ifelse(CUTS %in% 0:1,1,2))
}

colorScale <- data.frame(z=Z_Breaks(nfactor),
                         col=rep(foo,each=2),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


g <- list(
  fitbounds = "locations",
  visible = FALSE
)
fig <- plot_ly() 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(
  data=df,
  type="choropleth",
  geojson=geojson,
  locations= ~CODMPIO,
  z=df$test,
  colorscale=colorScale,
  colorbar=list(tickvals=1:nfactor, ticktext=names(foo)),
  featureidkey="properties.DPTOMPIO"
)
fig <- fig %>% layout(
  geo = g
)
fig
```

The first lines were done using the answer on this question [How to create a chloropleth map in R Plotly based on a Categorical variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516054/how-to-create-a-chloropleth-map-in-r-plotly-based-on-a-categorical-variable)

I get the following plot

[Resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g379.png)

It classifies the factors correctly, when I hover over it shows me the right value and right ID but as you can see it's not colouring as it should only the last row is being correctly coloured (the green one)